# Compute the volume bounded by the parabolic cylinders $x^2=4-4z, \quad y^2=4-4z$ and the $xy-$plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Compute the volume bounded by the parabolic cylinders $x^2=4-4z, \quad
> > y^2=4-4z$ and the $xy-$plane.

Say the $xy-$plane is the ground, the two cylindrcal paraboloids then make upp the roof, where the base is simply a square. Looking at this from above and onto the $xy-$ plane, the following image should emerge:

[image]

Hence the volume of this region should easily be computed by

$$V=\iiint_K1 \ dxdydz = 8\iint_D\left(\int_0^{1-x^2/4}1\right)\ dxdy=8\iint_D1-\frac{x^2}{4} \ dydx=$$

$$8\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\int_0^x1 \ dydx= 8\int_0^1x-\frac{x^3}{4} \ dx =\frac{7}{2}.$$

Correct answer: $V=8.$ Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the integral $x$ varies between $0$ and $2$, thus

$$8\int_0^2 x-\frac{x^3}{4} \ dx = \left[\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}{16}\right]_0^2=8(2-1)=8$$

Comment: I wish I could notice it, but I can't. Is my figure wrong?

Comment: Do you remember my suggestion? Draw picture of domain in $x-z$ and $y-z$ axis, for $z=0\implies x^2=4$.

Comment: I see it now, I se why. My figure is wrong indeed. should just be a bigger square by one.

Comment: I swear I did follow your suggestion, but I simply drew the wrong intersection values. Thank you!

Comment: @Parseval Yes exactly, you need to draw region accurately and alway start by simple sections in vertical and horizontal planes.

Comment: @Parseval Well done, you are always welcome! Bye